# PHP && or if else statement not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I have this survey that I am pulling results from and I have to basically make a bunch of `if...else if...` statements involving which feedback is submitted.

I have set it up to work correctly...except for one problem.  I know it's probably something stupid, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Anyways here is the code.

```
if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == "")) {
    echo "";
}
else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 3)) {
    echo $row_custom['Content'];
}
else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)) {
    echo $row_custom['Content2'];
}
else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] >= 7)) {
    echo $row_custom['Content3'];   
}
```

The problem I am getting is if `$row_result_2['Feedback']` is `==` to 5 or 6.  It just repeats the line over and over again, basically failing to evaluate.  It works fine for 4, so I am thinking my problem is somewhere in how I set up the `||` statements?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

While I'm at it would there be a simpler way to write this statement? So i don't have to copy it for each `QID_A` field 1-50?

UPDATE::
At this point I am at a loss as to why none of the below solutions are working.. I think this might be a deeper issue as the results are still repeating 24 times... Being that QID_A is 23 I think this might be related.. but I can't seem to find a connection... Thanks again for the help though guys I appreciate it.

Just for the hell of it I tried writing the statements out individually.... same result...
for example.

```
if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == "")) {
echo "";
 }
 else if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 3)) {
  echo $row_custom['Content'];
  }
  else if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4)) {
  echo $row_custom['Content2'];
 }
 else if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5)) {
  echo $row_custom['Content2'];
 }
 else if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)) {
  echo $row_custom['Content2'];
 }
 else if (($QID_A == 22) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] >= 7)) {
  echo $row_custom['Content3']; 
 }
```

Comment: What *does* it print out if you have a value of 5 or 6? What do you mean by 'repeats the line over and over'?

Comment: maybe $QID_A is the problem when you have 5 or 6 for $row_result_2['Feedback'] ..

Comment: it echo out the value of $row_custom['Content2']; 24 times

Comment: Do you have this structure inside another loop?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a while() loop `while ($row_result_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($feedbackQ3)) {'

Comment: Sounds innocuous alright, but I've a feeling there's something in the bits you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks Pete, finally tracked it down!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra pair of brackets to make it obvious what the precedence should be with your operators (and you don't need the brackets round each expression):

```
else if ($QID_A == 23 && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4 || $row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5 || $row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)) {
```

echo $row_custom['Content2'];
 }

But you might be better off writing this logic use a case so it's clearer, i.e.

```
if ($QID_A == 23) {
    switch( $row_result_2['Feedback'] ) {
      case '':
        echo '';
        break;
      case 0:
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        echo $row_custom['Content'];
        break;
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
        echo $row_custom['Content2'];
        break;
      default:
        echo $row_custom['Content3']; 
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Turned out it was displaying all the if else statements based on my previous error, this was a hard one to track down, ended up using your code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an if with a switch statment.

```
if ($QID_A == 23) {
    $feedback = $row_result_2['Feedback'];
    switch ($feedback) {
        case "":
            echo "";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            echo $row_custom['Content'];
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            echo $row_custom['Content2'];
            break;
        default:
            echo $row_custom['Content3'];
    }
}
```

I realize that the switch can get a little kludgey if you end up with more options but makes things a little easier.  You would also be able to break it into a function for the options 1 - 50 of the QID_A field.

Answer (score 1):

if you are saying that you don't get the same output for 5 and 6 as you do for 4 I don't know what's the problem (maybe you should double check the value)

But for the second part of the question, the one about another way to write this same thing I have this option:

```
if (23 == $QID_A)
{
    switch ($row_result_2['Feedback'])
    {
        case '':
            echo '';
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            echo $row_custom['Content'];
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            echo $row_custom['Content2'];
            break;
        default:
            echo $row_custom['Content3']; 
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's the role of **$QID_A** but just for this part it seems to be the same

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

I think you want:

```
else if (($QID_A == 23) && (($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6))) {
```

As for your other question, if you need have 50 questions, create a map, something like:

```
array(qID => array(array(valuesOfFeedback), contentNumber)
if( in_array($feedback, $map[$QID_A][0]) ) echo $map[$QID_A][1];
```

Comment: Right. Better safe than sorry with parentheses. `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so the original statement ends up working like `($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4)` or `($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5)` or `($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)`.

Comment: tried this one miki, it is still doing the same thing.  echoing out the value of $row_custom['Content2']; 24 times.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, which is a little more efficient, more legible and (hopefully) will fix the problem:

```
if ($QID_A == 23) {
  switch (TRUE) {
    case $row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 3:
      echo $row_custom['Content'];
      break;
    case $row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 6:
      echo $row_custom['Content2'];
      break;
    case $row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 7:
      echo $row_custom['Content3'];
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this does it.

```
<?php
        if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == "")) {
            echo "";
        }
        else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] <= 3)) {
            echo $row_custom['Content'];
        }
        else if (
        ($QID_A == 23 && $row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4) ||
        ($QID_A == 23 && $row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5 )||
        ($QID_A == 23 && $row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)
        ) {
            echo $row_custom['Content2'];
        }
        else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] >= 7)) {
            echo $row_custom['Content3'];
        }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry. It looked the same to me, but I just had a vague notion .... It reminded me of something I saw once. I'll try to come up with plan C.

Comment: No reason to apologize Pete, It appears the error is not in the statement, at least not that I can find.. Check the updates I made in the OP. I am still at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Instead `else if (($QID_A == 23) && ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6))` write `else if (($QID_A == 23) && (($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 4) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 5) || ($row_result_2['Feedback'] == 6)))`
Why? If && had the same priority as || your code, your code would work.